# Mock the implementation of Parent class method?

Tags: c#, oop

I want to mock the implementation of `Parent` class Test2 method so that it should return the child implementation.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var child = new Child();
        child.print();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
//Parent Class
public class Parent
{
    public void print()
    {
        Test1();
    }
    protected void Test1()
    {
        Test2();
    }

    protected void Test2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent Test2");
    }
}

//Child Class
public class Child : Parent
{
    protected void Test2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child Test2");
    }
}
```

Output : Parent Test2

But I want output to be Child Test2. Is there any way I can do this without modifying any code in parent class.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Java?

Comment: Because its OOP related question. Apology if I should not.

Comment: Only include tags which are directly relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Test2` needs to be marked as `virtual` in `Parent` and `override` in `Child` to have the semantics you want.

There is no way to have the semantics you want without modifying the `Parent` class.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I wanted no code change in Parent class

Comment: @TBAG Then you're out of luck.  The `Parent` implementation you provided is actively preventing the behavior that you want.  It's specifically designed to *prevent* any child classes from overriding the behavior of its methods by making them non-virtual.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but it is rather suggested to be left only for testing and research purposes as it would be a huge hack.

Have a look at this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer

In short words what you would have to do is to get the method handle at runtime and replace it for another method that implementes the call in the way you like. Then you can use reflection to access any other method.

This will work but should be avoided for any commercial and productive solutions I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it without having `virtual` in the `Parent`, you can define the following in `Child`:

```
    public new void print()
    {
        Test2();
    }
```

Then, change the definition of `Test2()` to also include the `new` keyword.  However, I wouldn't recommend this over just declaring `Test2()` as `virtual` if you can help it.

Simply defining both methods will already hide the implementation in the base class, but adding the `new` keyword makes it explicit that it is what you're intending to do.  Without the keyword, you will get a compiler warning as well.

Comment: Adding `new` here is only going to remove the warning, it won't change anything.  In particular this means that *he still doesn't have the desired semantics* and his program is going to be calling the wrong implementation of `Test2`.

Comment: @Servy I already said that in my answer. That's why he has to create a `print()` method in `Child` to hide the implementation in `Parent`.